# Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin-make, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I tryed to make a move group interface in c++, but when i try to build the package i get all this errors using catkin_make, I'm using Kinetic im ubuntu 16.04.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/a1de816ea92ad18729cc3966908ed920

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273790/invoking-%22make--j8--l8%22-failed/) by [Chrisch](https://answers.ros.org/users/32352/chrisch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you added a `add_definitions(-std=c++11)` statement somewhere in your `CMakeLists.txt`?

MoveIt needs C++11 enabled, otherwise you'll run into errors like these.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1